# detecting returned errors with $.post

Tags: jquery, http-post

I'm using $.post to send a query to a JSP which returns some awesome data for me.

If the query is malformed, however, the page returns with "error on page" and an HTTP Status of *500 Internal Server Error*

in jQuery, how can I detect this error so I can tell the user of the failure?

```
 runQuery : function () {
    $.post(
        admin_stats.runQueryURL,
        {
            buster   : Math.random,
            statsQuery: admin_stats.getQuery(),
            jsp: 'admin_statsQuery'
        },
        admin_stats.handleStatsQuery,
        "html"
    );
```

the returned data is an HTML table which is sufficient for this project at the moment.

Also: totally open to criticism if this is ugly or not the way I should be doing things =)

Comment: love that it returns "awesome data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `$.ajax` method instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: admin_stats.runQueryURL,
    data: {
        buster   : Math.random,
        statsQuery: admin_stats.getQuery(),
        jsp: 'admin_statsQuery'
    },
    success: admin_stats.handleStatsQuery,
    error: admin_stats.error, //change this to your handler
    dataType: "html"
});
```

See here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/). From the documentation:

> Register a handler to be called when
>   Ajax requests complete with an error.
>   This is an Ajax Event.

Documented example:

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
  if (settings.url == 'ajax/missing.html') {
    $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
  }
});
```

If you want to give a message specific to the type of error returned, you can do so like this:

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
     if(xhr.status == 500) { 
         $(this).text('internal server error');
     } else if (xhr.status == 404) { 
         $(this).text('page not found');
     }
     // etc.
});
```